# How to restrict a page for subscriber in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How i can restrict any page or url in admin for subscriber role.

Example: i want to restrict this url :- **post-new.php?post_type=knowledge_share_post** only for subscriber role in admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try Role Scoper Plugin.
which url below.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/

Comment: @Amandeep Wadhawan if your problem solve with this plugin info me.